# Query to remove duplicate rows from mysql database table

Tags: mysql, row

I would like to write a query to remove duplicate rows from my database table 
here is a screenshot of my table in mysql workbench
Here are the columns that I have for my table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfF4q.png)

If all of the column values are the same (except for the ID of course) then I only want to keep one copy of the row instead of having it multiple times. So if all the values are equal among the columns of the table then I only want to keep one copy of the row.
[image]

Here are my columns

## Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra

'id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'

'callermethodid', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'callername', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'callerclass', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'callerclassid', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'fullcaller', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'calleemethodid', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'calleename', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'calleeclass', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'calleeclassid', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'fullcallee', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'fullmethod', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

Comment: how we can check duplication value? Which column values duplication you want to check?

Comment: I just added more info